# How to read S3 part files into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I have unloaded data from redshift to S3, after unloading I got xx_0000_part_00 multiple file.

Now I want to read these file into pandas dataframe.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Som

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import the file from s3 to your local or ec2 using

> aws s3 cp

command. Once you have the file locally, just read it through pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/file-path/filename')
```

PS - S3 part file is just a regular csv file with your chosen delimiter. 

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this package if you want to get data from redshift into pandas (or get the data from pandas to redshift):

https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift